# LinkedIn API | what is unique for a user in LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I have seen this issue and its kind of open on LinkedIn, http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/different-id-same-user-using-oauth would like to know if someone has faced this issue and got a solution in any way. Any help would be appreciated. Facing a problem related to this issue and not sure how should I approach. For summary on this issue go through post #10

http://developer.linkedin.com/comment/29644#comment-29644

Answer (score 5):

User ids are API key dependent. For a given API key and user we always return the same unique UserID. You will never get the same UserID for two different people. There is no way to decrypt these IDs, this has been done primarily to protect the privacy of our users

But If a member has chosen to opt out of data sharing with third parties, requests for their profile return as private for id and last-name. (This means id is not a unique field.) read this http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

Comment: what is the solution to this problem if the only unique identifier is keep on changing with every API key change. There should be a unique way to identify user. FYI, email address also is not unique in linkedIn as user can change firms and then user can choose to make other email id primary.

Comment: Use one API key and exclude uses who has id="private". because they are not useful for your application they are not provide any information.

Comment: Using one API key may not be feasible solution because doing that creates a big dependency on IIIrd party. Moreover we may need to change the keys too in future then it will be a problem.

Comment: you are using third party application(Linkedin) then you always depend on this.even I don't think API key is change for any case.

Answer (score 3):

No two linkedin users can have same linkedin ID. So that way, linkedin IDs are unique. But you will get a different linkedin IDs for the same user if you use different API keys to make a call to linkedin API. Hope it's clear. So if you are using a single API key throughout your application, you don't have to worry about it at all. But if you are using multiple API keys, you can store a set of linkedin IDs for a particular user (instead of a single ID through single API key) to identify a user uniquely on linkedin.

Comment: Please check comment on @Naveen's post. Thanks for help.

Comment: I was trying to convey the exact same information what @Naveen has explained (though he has done it in more explainable manner). You can identify linkedin users uniquely(except for those whose id is private). But yes, just like him, even I am not been able to imagine the use case where you will need to change your API key in the future.

Answer (score 0):

How about site-standard-profile-request field. Query string of this field contains "id" parameter. In different Api Keys, ID value remains unique.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile